# Sending click event to an inactive window

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a simple script, that press the `1` key and then clicks on specific X,Y coordinates on an **inactive window**.

Here's my code

```
$1::
Loop
{
;   ControlClick, X682 Y515, ahk_pid 8356

    ControlSend, , 1, ahk_pid 8356
    Sleep, 300
    ControlSend, , {Click 682, 515}, ahk_pid 8356
    Sleep, 300
}
Return
```

The `ControlSend` command to press the `1` button works, but the `{Click}` doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The program I was trying to use it with is Ragnarok Online. It seems it works with every other program, just not with Ragnarok, which means this probably doesn't have a solution.